# Is there a way to auto backup my phone files to my PC via wifi?

Tags: applications, backup

I am looking for a way to automatically transfer files in my phone to my PC (Win7) if my phone connects to my home wifi network. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean your photos/music etc. that are stored on the 'sdcard' (even though it may not be an actual SD card). If so there are a number of apps that can do this.

I personally use [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) (There is a [lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) version with some limitations)

Another option is [SyncMe Wireless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bv.wifisync) but i've not used it so can't comment on how good it is.

Comment: Can you sync an offline folder like /Desktop/DontWantCloud/ ?

Comment: @user1603548 as long as it's accessible on the network you can sync any folder you like without needing to go via the internet/cloud.

Comment: You may want to be careful about recommending Cheetah apps based on a new report out about Cheetah, and Google Play actions against them. See this: [https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/).

Answer (score 0):

try [BitTorent Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.sync&hl=en). Its the best i have ever used. After all its torrent.